# Change Azure AD B2C User Password with Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to use the [Sample Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) app to change a user's password but I'm getting:

**Error Calling the Graph API Response:**

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}
```

**Graph API Request:**

```
PATCH /mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/some-guid?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
client-request-id: ffd564d3-d716-480f-a66c-07b02b0e32ab
date-time-utc: 2017.08.10 03:04 PM
```

**JSON File**

```
{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "Somepassword1$",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    }
}
```

I've tested updating the user's `displayName` and that works fine.

```
{
    "displayName": "Joe Consumer"
}
```

**AD Application Permissions**

I've configured [my app permissions as described here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-create-read-and-update-permissions-for-your-application)

[image: AD App Permissions]

Comment: Can you please post a correlation ID + timestamp from this error?

Comment: where is the correlation id?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593823/wheres-the-correlation-id-in-the-graph-api-response

Comment: I've added it.  Thanks for your help! @DanielDobalian

Comment: Hey @DanielDobalian , any updates?  thanks.

Comment: How did you authorize the graph api reques?  i mean how did you get bearer token ?

Comment: I didn't.  It doesn't work that way.  It uses a `secret`.  See `<add key="b2c:ClientSecret" value="{The Key from above}" />` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).  You might want to open another question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2016/01/graph-api-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation.html). Seems like it has the same symptoms.

**Solution 1:**

If you are receiving this error when you call the API that includes only read permissions, you have to set permissions in Azure Management Portal.

- Go to Azure Management Portal and click Active Directory.
- Select your custom AD directory.
- Click Applications and select your Application.
- Click CONFIGURE and scroll down to the section 'Permissions to other applications'.
- Provide required Application Permissions and Delegated Permissions for Windows Azure Active Directory.
- Finally save the changes.

**Solution 2:**

If you are receiving this error when you call the API that includes `delete` or `reset password` operations, that is because those operations require the Admin role of `Company Administrator`.  As of now, you can only add this role via the [Azure AD Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0).

1. Find the service principal using Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId

   ```
   Get-MsolServicePrincipal | ft DisplayName, AppPrincipalId -AutoSize
   ```
2. Use Add-MsolRoleMember to add it to `Company Administrator` role

   ```
   $clientIdApp = 'your-app-id'
   $webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $clientIdApp

   Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId
   ```

To connect to your B2C tenant via PowerShell you will need a local admin account.  [This blog post should help](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2016/07/25/creating-azure-ad-b2c-service-principals-with-powershell/) with that, see "The Solution" section.

[image: create global admin]

[image: connect via powershell]

[image: get-msolservice principal screenshot]

[image: add role screenshot]

Comment: thanks @Parakh! I'm thinking solution 1 is for the old portal.  Please confirm.  I'm not seeing those options in portal.azure.com

Comment: nvm, I've confirmed, that's for the old portal.  I've already granted 'read and write directory data' as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-create-read-and-update-permissions-for-your-application

Comment: solution 2 was the fix.

Comment: One important thing! To be able to to see the correct directory you need to create __local__ Azure B2C Administrator (for example admin@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com) and log-in with ```Connect-MsolService``` and his credential with AzureAD PowerShell, otherwise you wouldn't be able to get the Application with the ```Get-MsolServicePrincipal``` because of different directory. See _Important_ section in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-delete-permissions-for-your-application).

Answer (score 0):

Try below settings, works for me.

[image]

Used the below JSON

```
 {
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "kart.kala1@test.com"
    }
  ],
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Joe Consumer",
  "mailNickname": "joec",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "P@$$word!",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
  "givenName": "Joe",
}
```

Also make sure you assign the application the user account, administrator role which will allow it to delete users [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#configure-delete-permissions-for-your-application)

Comment: are you sure you can change a password w/ those settings? did you try and update user with the json above?

Comment: check the json in the answer