# Where's the Correlation ID in the Graph API Response?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to provide the `correlation id` for this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577620/change-azure-ad-b2c-user-password-with-graph-api?noredirect=1#comment78118588_45577620) but I'm not sure how to obtain it.  I assume it should be in response, is that correct?  Is it the client-request-id maybe?

**HTTP Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: CGa9FFPZASZM+usTGvTzaOZ4zSMxhpbWh2mO9+eJZWs=
request-id: 6ddd7a86-02c9-4dcf-9932-b17afc976107
client-request-id: 50478d75-542d-4e0e-96d9-de913d632471
x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.6
ocp-aad-session-key: some-really-long-value
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Duration: 782602
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2017 14:22:21 GMT
Content-Length: 139

{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

**Token Request Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
client-request-id: 8c500700-b75c-403a-a2c9-c6dfa27049d3
x-ms-request-id: 75627b63-fbd6-4fa8-95b5-b6a325d60900
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Set-Cookie: esctx=some-value; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=006; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2017 18:33:33 GMT
Content-Length: 1437

{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"262800","expires_on":"1502307214","not_before":"1502303314","resource":"https://graph.windows.net/","access_token":"some-token-value"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correlation ID (also called client-request-id) can be found in interactions with the Azure AD service.

The request immediately before this when you were asking the Azure AD endpoints for tokens will include the ID in the response.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/...`

`https://login.windows.net/...`

Comment: I've added the response when I obtain a token.  I still don't see the correlation id.

Comment: @spottedmahn hey I updated the answer. client-request-id is the equivalent!