# Azure Corelation Id and Request ID

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, postman, azureportal

I have an Azure account and I am making AD API calls for that account using postman, due to some issue I contacted Microsoft and they are asking for Correlation ID and request ID for the same, where can I find these two things?

This is the API I have been calling
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: How are you making this API call? In your code or using Fiddler?

Comment: I was doing using code earlier, but using postman or fiddler is also an option, I am calling Active Directory User Delta API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information in the response headers. For example, when I execute a failed request, this is what I get in the response headers when I use Graph Explorer:

```
{
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "preference-applied": "odata.track-changes",
    "request-id": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
}
```

I was not able to find any documentation however I believe `client-request-id` response header is the correlation id and `request-id` response header is the request id you're looking for.

For errors, this information is also included in the error response body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-07-09T12:50:35",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on [Where's the Correlation ID in the Graph API Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593823/wheres-the-correlation-id-in-the-graph-api-response), `client-request-id` is the correlation id.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, still trying to figure out the correlation ID part though, tried List Deployment API however it didnt work because of access issues, is there any other way through which I can get correlation ID, I have client id, client secret, tenant id, service principal id with me for that account

Comment: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593823/wheres-the-correlation-id-in-the-graph-api-response), `client-request-id` is the correlation id.

Comment: client-id and client-request-id, both are exactly similar in my response header
This is one documentation I was able to find out, looks like correlation id might be different from client-request-id  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-history?tabs=http

Comment: The link you mentioned is for Azure Resource Manager API which is completely different than Graph API. You may want to share the values you got with Azure Support and see if they consider `client-request-id` as correlation id.