# Change user password for using Azure Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am not able to change the password of the logged in Azure AD B2C user.
I have Azure B2C tenant which is used for dev and QA.Also, i have two applications something-Local and something-QA used for DEV and QA respectively in Azure B2C as shown below and I have verified the settings of both the apps they are same [image]
Below are the configurations of the applications 
Here is my code which is used for B2C connection

```
 private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            // meta data
            MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + "mytenant" + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=" + policy,
            AuthenticationType = policy,

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = AzureAdConfig.ClientId,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
            },
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
            }
        };
    }
```

**in the above code the ClientID used for QA and Dev are different.**
Below is the code used to change the user password using graph API.

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ChangePassword(string currentPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        string userId = ClaimValues.ObjectIdentifier();
        var adUser = _activeDirectoryClient.Users
            .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userId))
            .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault();

        string upn = adUser.UserPrincipalName;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string uriString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ AzureAdConfig.Tenant + "/oauth2/token";
        Uri requestUri = new Uri(uriString);
        string requestString = "resource=https%3a%2f%2fgraph.windows.net&client_id=" + AzureAdConfig.AppId + "&grant_type=password&username=" + upn + "&password=" + currentPassword + "&client_secret=" + AzureAdConfig.AppKey;
        var tokenResult = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        if (tokenResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stringResult = await tokenResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            GraphApiTokenResult objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphApiTokenResult>(stringResult);
            client = new HttpClient();
            string requestUrl = AzureAdConfig.GraphResourceId + AzureAdConfig.Tenant + "/me/changePassword?" + AzureAdConfig.GraphVersion;
            Uri graphUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", objectResult.access_token);
            requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                currentPassword = currentPassword,
                newPassword = newPassword
            });
            var response = await client.PostAsync(graphUri, new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return tokenResult;
        }
    }
```

Also, i wanted to understand what is the difference between Application Registrations in Azure Active directory service of azure and the Application in Azure AD B2C of azure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change user password by using Azure AD Graph API, first you should be a [global administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) in your tenant, and then you could use `PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version` and then update.

```
    {
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  }
}
```

> Also, i wanted to understand what is the difference between
>   Application Registrations in Azure Active directory service of azure
>   and the Application in Azure AD B2C of azure?

You can know about this from the difference between Azure AD tenant and Azure AD B2C tenant from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628730/whats-the-difference-between-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-and-normal-azure-ad-tenant).

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I know password can be changed using [admin account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577620/change-azure-ad-b2c-user-password-with-graph-api).I was trying to do [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword) way, but I have two applications registered in Azure AD B2C(not regular AD)=> Applications, if I use client id and secret of these apps it works for both apps only in my local, but out of 2 apps only one application works from deployed(as app service in azure)  version. Am I missing some configuration for the deployed version.

Comment: I'm confused about you mentioned. As I know, the Azure AD Graph Explorer can be only logged in with user credentials, it cannot be used by the applications. And by using the [way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword) you used, the target user must be the signed-in user, which means you can only change the user password that you are logging in.

Comment: And if you use Patch https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version, you require to be a administrator in the Azrue AD B2C tenant. However, if you use Post https://graph.windows.net/me/changePassword?api-version, it not requires administrator.